# Using for example filter() method, how can I return the elements that meet the condition and its index value at the same time?

Tags: javascript, indexing, filter

Here a code as an example:

```
const nums = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

    oddArr = arrNum.filter(function(num,index){
      return num % 2 != 0
    })

    evenArr = arrNum.filter(function(num,index){
      return num % 2 === 0
    })
```

Here I would like to return the new array with the original index of each element that meet the condition. I tried placing a , after the condition (num % 2 === 0) but nothing

In case of  looking for odds number, I would like to get an output like this (bold data refers to the index of that number in the original array:
[1,**0**,1,**1**,3,**2**] 
Maybe get an object for each result would be better. Something like this:

```
[
{1,0},
{1,1},
{3,2}
]
```

I dont even know if its possible,but I wonder because this other code effectively works:

```
function array_odd_even_position(a) {
   return a.filter((num,index) => console.log(num,index));
}

array_odd_even_position([1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Can you please share the expected output also.

Comment: So do you want an array of just the indices? Or an array of elements that meet the condition as well as an array of indices? Your question title indicates the latter but your post indicates the former

Comment: The latter it´s the one I´m looking for

Answer (score 3):

`filter` by itself isn't helpful here, since it will always return the values of the array, never its indexes. However, this'll do:

```
oddIndexes = arrNum.map((_, idx) => idx).filter(idx => arrNum[idx] % 2)
```

First map your array to an array of indexes, then filter those. You could use `reduce` to do it in one iteration:

```
oddIndexes = arrNum.reduce((acc, n, idx) => {
    if (n % 2) {
        acc.push(idx);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes, this code extract the index of the odd numbers, but I meant, extract the odd numbers and also the index of them on the original array. Maybe I didn´t explain properly

Comment: Maybe I just provided an illustrative sample and you can customise that to really fit your needs…

Answer (score 2):

Since filter can only filter elements and you need both filter and to modify returned values you could use `reduce` method and do the both in one go.

```js
const nums = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

const { odd, even } = nums.reduce((r, e, i) => {
  let key = (e % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
  r[key].push(i)
  return r
}, { odd: [], even: [] })


console.log(odd)
console.log(even)
```